# Recording with Quicktime through Java

Tags: java, applescript, quicktime

I want to make a recording with Quicktime using Java but there is some issue when I try to enter the folder and file. I though it might be a timing issue so put in delays but it still happens. The code to start the recording is:

```
public static void startQTrecord(){     
        //Activate QT
        try{
            String[] go = { "osascript", "-e", "tell application \"QuickTime Player\" to activate" };
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }    
        //Start new recording
        try{
            String[] go = { "osascript", "-e", "tell application \"QuickTime Player\" to start new movie recording" };
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();    
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

And the code to stop and save is:

```
public static void closeQT(){
        //Go to QT
        try {
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", "tell application \"QuickTime Player\" to activate"};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        //Stop the recording
        try {
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", "tell application \"QuickTime Player\" to stop document \"movie recording\""};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        //Save
        try {
            sleep(100);
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"s\" using {command down}", "-e", "delay 1"};         
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
        process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        //Enter the save directory
        try {
            sleep(100);
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"G\" using {command down, shift down}", "-e", "delay 1"};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            sleep(100);
            String gofolder = "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" + folder + "\"";
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", gofolder, "-e", "delay 1", "-e", "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return", "-e", "delay 1"};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            sleep(100);
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke\""+file+"\"", "-e", "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return", "-e", "delay 1"};         
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Wait for save then quit
        boolean keepWaiting = true;
        while(keepWaiting){
            try{
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                String[] commands = {"osascript", "-e", "delay 5", "-e", "tell application \"QuickTime Player\" to quit"};
                Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
                proc.waitFor();
                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
                String s = null;
                // read any errors from the attempted command
                if(stdError.readLine() == null){keepWaiting = false;}
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Sometimes it works fine but other times it will get to the folder window and not paste in the correct text.

Any ideas on why this isn't working or if there is a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use the appleScript's **save** command instead of using the **keystroke** command

```
public static void closeQT(){
        //Pause the recording, save and quit
        try {
            String[] go = {"osascript", "-e", "set tFile to \""+fullPosixPathOfFile+"\" as posix file", "-e", "do shell script \"touch \" & quoted form of posix path of tFile", "-e", "tell application \"QuickTime Player\"", "-e", "pause document 1", "-e", "save document 1 in tFile", "-e", "stop document 1", "-e", "close document 1 saving no", "-e", "quit", "-e", "end tell"};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(go);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

put the file path where you want to save the movie in the `fullPosixPathOfFile` variable

---

Here's an example of an AppleScript that works

```
set tFile to (path to desktop folder as string) & "MyMovie.mov" -- save the movie to the desktop

do shell script "touch " & quoted form of POSIX path of tFile  --  "QuickTime Player" need an existing file (otherwise permissions issue), so the touch command create an empty file 
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    launch
    set newMovieRec to new movie recording
    tell newMovieRec
        start
        delay 10 -- duration in seconds of this new movie
        pause
        save in (file tFile) -- The term "file" is necessary when the type of the path is HFS (path with colon character --> "diskName:folder1:subFolder2:myMovie.mov")
        --save in tFile -- use this line when the tFile variable contains a posix file (a posix path converted to a posix file)
        stop
        close saving no
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

---

To check the version of **Quicktime**:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set v to version
    considering numeric strings
        set newVersion to v > "7.6.6" -- change it to the old version which not work
    end considering
    if newVersion then
        -- code to save
    else
        -- code to save as
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try this I get an error message that "The document could not be saved. You don't have permission." despite having read/write access to all the folders I wanted to save to. Any ideas?

Comment: Because `tFile` contains a string (HFS path, path with colon character) , the script need the `file` term --> `save in (file tFile)`. I change it in my answer. 

If you use a posix path, convert it to posix file, like this example --> `set tFile to "/Users/myUserName/Desktop/MyMovie.mov" as posix file`

Comment: I still get the same message :(

Comment: Just a slight modification works - change the "save" line to "save in (tFile as POSIX file). THANKS!!

Comment: This works for new versions of QuickTime but older ones do not have a "save" command - they use a "save as". How can the applescript be modified to cater for both?